# What is web context in the following context (java ee tutorials)

Tags: java-ee-6

I am reading the Java EE 6 Tutorials pdf document from official site.
I am reading the part related with servlets, where it says:

> **Associating Objects with a Session** 
>   You can associate object-valued
>   attributes with a session by name. Such attributes are accessible by
>   any web component that belongs to the same web context and is handling
>   a request that is part of the same session.

I wonder what is the web context and how it can be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the same web context means ServletContext, please refer the seciton **7.4 Binding Attributes into a Session** of servlet 3.0 specification:

> A servlet can bind an object attribute into an HttpSession
>   implementation by name. Any object bound into a session is available
>   to any other servlet that belongs to the same ServletContext and
>   handles a request identified as being a part of the same session.